Azure Notification Hub 410 Unauthorized error when calling from .NET Core backend
I am attempting to register a device to Azure Notifications Hub from a .NET Core backend. Using the DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature name and connection string to connect to the Azure NH. None of the methods are working and are throwing an error

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Reason: Unauthorized

Not sure what I am missing but tried scouring the internet for solutions and no luck so far.
Here is my backend code which connects with and calls the Azure Notification Hub resource:
private NotificationHubClient _hub;
private Dictionary<string, NotificationPlatform> _installationPlatform;
private TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

public PushNotificationsHelper(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
{
    _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
    _hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(NotificationHubOptions.ConnectionString, NotificationHubOptions.Name);

    _installationPlatform = new Dictionary<string, NotificationPlatform>
    {
        { nameof(NotificationPlatform.Apns).ToLower(), NotificationPlatform.Apns },
        { nameof(NotificationPlatform.Fcm).ToLower(), NotificationPlatform.Fcm },
    };
}

public async Task<bool> CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(DeviceInstallation deviceInstallation, CancellationToken token)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceInstallation?.InstallationId) ||
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceInstallation?.Platform) ||
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceInstallation?.PushChannel))
        return false;

    var installation = new Installation()
    {
        InstallationId = deviceInstallation.InstallationId,
        PushChannel = deviceInstallation.PushChannel,
        Tags = deviceInstallation.Tags
    };

    if (_installationPlatform.TryGetValue(deviceInstallation.Platform, out var platform))
        installation.Platform = platform;
    else
        return false;

    try
    {
        await _hub.CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync(installation, token);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

Even calling the CreateRegistrationIdAsync method is throwing the same error.

Check this  once.

I have used the below code and successfully registered a device with Azure Notification Hub using DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature in a .NET Core application.

to register a device to Azure Notifications Hub from a .NET Core backend. Using the DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature

The issue you are facing typically occurs with authorization.
Ensure your ConnectionString and Azure Notification Hub name are correct.
DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature should have "Listen" and "Manage" permissions to perform registration operations.
I used the code below to register the device to the NotificationHub.
NotificationHubService :
using Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace NotificationHubDemo.Services
{
    public class NotificationHubService
    {
        private readonly NotificationHubClient _hubClient;
        public NotificationHubService(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var connectionString = configuration["NotificationHub:ConnectionString"];
            var hubName = configuration["NotificationHub:HubName"];
            _hubClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(connectionString, hubName);
        }
        public async Task<string> RegisterDeviceAsync(string deviceToken, string platform)
        {
            var registrationId = await _hubClient.CreateRegistrationIdAsync();
            RegistrationDescription registrationDescription;
            if (platform == "gcm") 
            {
                registrationDescription = new GcmRegistrationDescription(deviceToken);
            }
            else if (platform == "apns") 
            {
                registrationDescription = new AppleRegistrationDescription(deviceToken);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Platform not supported");
            }

            registrationDescription.RegistrationId = registrationId;
            await _hubClient.CreateOrUpdateRegistrationAsync(registrationDescription);

            return registrationId;
        }
        public async Task UnregisterDeviceAsync(string registrationId)
        {
            await _hubClient.DeleteRegistrationAsync(registrationId);
        }
    }
}

NotificationController:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using NotificationHubDemo.Models;
using NotificationHubDemo.Services;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace NotificationHubDemo.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class NotificationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly NotificationHubService _notificationHubService;

        public NotificationController(NotificationHubService notificationHubService)
        {
            _notificationHubService = notificationHubService;
        }
        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterDevice([FromBody] DeviceRegistrationRequest request)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.DeviceToken) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Platform))
            {
                return BadRequest("DeviceToken and Platform are required.");
            }
            var registrationId = await _notificationHubService.RegisterDeviceAsync(request.DeviceToken, request.Platform);
            return Ok(new { RegistrationId = registrationId });
        }
        [HttpPost("unregister")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UnregisterDevice([FromBody] UnregisterRequest request)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.RegistrationId))
            {
                return BadRequest("RegistrationId is required.");
            }
            await _notificationHubService.UnregisterDeviceAsync(request.RegistrationId);
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}

appsettings.json:
"NotificationHub": {
  "ConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://<NotificationHubNameSpace>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=<KeyValue>",
  "HubName": "<Notification_Hub_Name>"
},

Output:



@user16716435 Did you get a chance to look into the solution? let me know if you need more details.
